Render an Rmd to html in a loop
I have an Rmd script which produces an interactive 3D image using plotRGL() and rglwidget.
I need to generates 10 different html, one for each variable I'm working with.
If I knit the Rmd directly, the output is OK and of small size (aprox 1.5 Mb) but if I use a loop to render in sequence all traits :
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(sessioninfo)
load('lista.Rdata')

for (i in seq(1:length(lista))){
param1<-i
render("FatvsBHB_3D.Rmd",
       params = list(
         trait= param1
       ),
       output_format = "html_document", output_file=paste0('3D/FatvsBHB_3D_',lista[i],'.html'))
}

I got all HTML but their size is 10 times greater. It seems like each separate HTML output contains all HTML.
Any ideas?
Stefano
